# How to make styles inheritance for angular2 material2 directives

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Based on the template here below, the title is styled with inheritance (font : Roboto) but not the menuTitle variable (other font is applied).

When moving menuTitle at the same level as title, inheritance works.

```
<md-sidenav-layout [class.m2app-dark]="isDarkTheme">

  <md-toolbar>
    {{ title }}
  </md-toolbar>

  <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" align="end" opened="true" class="app-sidenav">
     {{ menuTitle }}
  </md-sidenav>
</md-sidenav-layout>
```

How can I do to have style inheritance for menuTitle var ?